# Overriding MKMapView scroll/pan has very poor performance

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

I want to restrict the panning of an `MKMapView` to horizontal/longitude scrolling only.

I set the latitude I want to keep in a var:

```
var currentLatitude: CLLocationDegrees?
```

Then I override the `mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion` delegate method to reset the map to the latitude if it's changed. It works, however the panning performance is horrible.

```
    func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
        
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLatitude ?? mapView.region.center.latitude, longitude: mapView.region.center.longitude)
        let newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, span: mapView.region.span)
        mapView.setRegion(newRegion, animated: false)
    }
```

I tried using the same code in `regionDidChangeAnimated` which works, however it allows vertical panning then when the users finger is lifted off it jumps back to the correct latitude.

There's also `regionWillChangeAnimated` but I don't believe this gives you the new coordinates before it changes.

Comment: Horizontal scrolling would be constant latitude. Vertical scrolling would be constant longitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `CameraBoundary` for the `MKMapView` with a latitudinal span of zero and maximum longitudinal span, for example:

```
let coordinateRegion =  MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5072, longitude: -0.1276),
                                           latitudinalMeters: 0,
                                           longitudinalMeters: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)

let boundary = MKMapView.CameraBoundary(coordinateRegion: coordinateRegion)

mapView.setCameraBoundary(boundary, animated: false)
```